# How do I check to see if a whole component is on screen?

Tags: java, swing, components, bounds, swingutilities

I'm working with a 3rd party plugin which includes a customized popup. This popup is added to a tab pane and when it appears, if to close to the JFrame border, only part of it will appear and the rest will draw off screen, as if it is behind the JFrame.

Is there anyway to check if a component bounds or its shape is completely visible to the user?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the javadocs for [SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointToScreen%28java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component%29).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't quite understand how this works. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi Steven - what you'd want to do is get the lower-right point of the control you'd like to check and convert that point to a screen coordinate. Having done that, you can check whether that coordinate is within the screen bounds.